# GeoJson to TopoJson converter with Attributes

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, geojson, topojson

I have GeoJson file converted from .shap file. each object has arc , points and some other property . Now When i tried to converter This GeoJson file to TopoJson file with this online app  http://shancarter.github.io/distillery/  the converted TopoJson is Working Greate with D3.js But the object has only type: Polygon and arc attributes. all other attributes like id , GEOFIP etc are gone. I need these not all but at-least 2-3 attributes must need to add some more functionality to map in D3.js

Answer (score 3):

you can convert to topojson using http://geojson.io, or http://mapshaper.org

Comment: their app crashed after uploading GeoJson file. File size is 42MB

Comment: which? mapshaper takes huge files